# Prevent C++ Builder from updating the .h file when saving changes to the .cpp file

Tags: c++builder

In newer versions of C++ Builder, it seems that whenever I make a change to the .cpp file and save it, the .h and .dfm files also get updated (at least their timestamps do).  As a result, a make then must compile every unit that includes the .h file, even though that file has not changed.

I don't think it used to do that.  Am I missing an editor option so that only the changed files (i.e. .cpp and/or .dfm) and not the .h file will be saved with an updated modify time?

I am using RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 update 2.  I am running in a Parallels virtual machine in Windows 10, within Mac High Sierra 10.13.4.

When I create a new C++ VCL project, it creates .cpp, .h, and .dfm files for the unit.

Interestingly, the updated modify time only appears when the project is being saved to the Mac disk; when saved to the disk within the virtual machine, only the .cpp file's modify time is updated (which is the correct behavior).  Because the content of the .h file is not changed (only its modify time), there is no change that shows in git.

So maybe this has something to do with the way the Parallels virtual machine is presenting the disk volume.

Comment: It would help to say exactly which version you are using. And perhaps you can use source control to find out exactly what the changes are. (I guess perhaps it might be updating function declaration in the header when you change the function in the body)

Comment: AFAIK, units that use the VCL have associated .hpp files, not .h files. The .cpp, .hpp and .dfm for such (form or datamodule) units are maintained by the IDE and AFAIK, they have always been updated by the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The version is  RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 update 2.  When I create new units, the IDE creates .h files.  Source control shows that no changes are being made to the .h files, but only that the timestamp is being updated.  That is not the behavior when the source code is on the C: drive.